# create a perfect ring of 6 images using jQuery and .css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been trying to figure this out for a while, I want to create an experiment where the images on the screen are maintained at a set visual angle, no matter how many pixels their computer screen has.

The code that adjusts the size of the stimuli seems to work fine, but I'm having difficulty with re-positioning the stimuli into a perfect circle. The zones are absolutely positioned within a major zone (see the first image below of zones placed in a ring - this is where my images will go), and I am using .css 'top' and 'left' to try and pull the images into a perfect ring based on the visual angle.

[image: picture]

```
var mainStimuliWidth = 2.3;
var mainStimuliHeight = 2.3;

gorillaTaskBuilder.onScreenStart((spreadsheet: any, rowIndex: number, screenIndex: number, row: any, container: string) => {
    $('body').css('background-color', BACKGROUND_COLOUR);
    $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, span').css('color', TEXT_COLOUR);
    if(row.display == _requiredRTDisplay){
        if(screenIndex == _requiredRTScreen){
        $(window).resize();
        // create variable for pixels per degree
        var PxPerDeg = gorilla.retrieve('pixels_per_degree', null, true)
        //find each zone
        var Zone1 = $(container + ' .Zone1');
        var Zone2 = $(container + ' .Zone2');
        var Zone3 = $(container + ' .Zone3');
        var Zone4 = $(container + ' .Zone4');
        var Zone5 = $(container + ' .Zone5');
        var Zone6 = $(container + ' .Zone6');
        //resize each zone based on pixels per degree
        Zone1.css('height', (mainStimuliHeight * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        Zone1.css('width', (mainStimuliWidth * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        Zone2.css('height', (mainStimuliHeight * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        Zone2.css('width', (mainStimuliWidth * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        Zone3.css('height', (mainStimuliHeight * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        Zone3.css('width', (mainStimuliWidth * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        Zone4.css('height', (mainStimuliHeight * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        Zone4.css('width', (mainStimuliWidth * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        Zone5.css('height', (mainStimuliHeight * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        Zone5.css('width', (mainStimuliWidth * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        Zone6.css('height', (mainStimuliHeight * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        Zone6.css('width', (mainStimuliWidth * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        
        // create positioning variables  
        
        var Position1 = (2.3*PxPerDeg).toString();
        var Position2 = (-2.3*PxPerDeg).toString();
        // reposition stimuli
        
        // timeout 
                setTimeout(function(){ 
          
          Zone1.css('top', Position1 + 'px');
          Zone2.css('top', Position2 + 'px');      
          Zone3.css('top', (Position1/2) + 'px');
          Zone3.css('left', (Position1*.866) + 'px');
          Zone4.css('top', (Position1/2) + 'px');
          Zone4.css('left', (Position1*.866) + 'px');
          Zone5.css('top', (-Position2/2) + 'px');
          Zone5.css('left', (-Position2*.866) + 'px');
          Zone6.css('top', (-Position2/2) + 'px');
          Zone6.css('left', (-Position2*.866) + 'px');
                
            }, 200);
        }
    }
```

With this code, the current stimuli look positioned like this (see the pictures with the black background with the circles and diamond - the first image is me setting a large number of pixels per degree, the second image is me setting a small amount of pixels per degree ). The idea is that as pixels INCREASE per visual degree, the stimuli should get bigger and further apart to maintain the same visual angle. On a smaller screen, when pixels per degree decrease, the stimuli should get smaller and closer together to maintain a perfect ring. I know the maths isn't right, but I'm just trying to make things move systematically. Ideally, I want the diameter of the ring to be 10.1 visual degrees and each stimulus around the ring to be 2.3x2.3 degrees.

If anyone knows how I can position these stimuli, I'd be super grateful!

[image: first picture]
[image: second image]

Comment: Oh also: Zone 1 = top image
Zone 2 = bottom image 
Zone 3 = top right
Zone 4 = bottom right 
Zone 5 = top left
Zone 6 = bottom left

Comment: Could you explain what the PxPerDeg represents?

Comment: PxPerDegree is how many pixels there are in one visual degree. Most desktop computers have around 30-40 pixels per degree, but the larger your screen, the more pixels there will be. 

This variable is calculated by getting participants to put a real credit card/business card up to their screen, and measuring a virtual one against it. This calibrates how many pixels there are per degree and stores it.

Comment: Visual degrees is used to maintain stimulus size across different screens. It's the size of the image that appears on your retina.

Comment: Afraid I'm lost. pixel is a linear measurement (whether one is talking about CSS or screen pixels) how is that related to degrees?

Answer (score 0):

This entire layout should be a lot easier to accomplish by just using CSS to position all of the DOM elements without having to try to figure out all the math to place the menu items in a circle. You can just create your menu elements in your container box and let that box drive the size and position of your elements.

Each menu item can be placed inside a box that stretches the length of your menu container. This is the radius of your menu. Inside these radius containers, you can have your actual menu items. Absolutely position them in a stack in the middle of your menu, then just rotate each of the radius containers evenly depending on how many there are, then reverse the rotation on the menu items.

The radius containers will prevent clicking the menu items but you can disable pointer events on those and re-enable the pointer events on the menu items.

[image]

[I threw together a codesandbox showing how this would work](https://codesandbox.io/s/circular-menu-fkkhw?file=/src/styles.scss). Note: The sandbox uses React just to quickly throw the markup together, and there is SCSS as a preprocessor, but this markup and CSS could be used anywhere.